# Filtering and Styling WFS GeoJSON

Tags: leaflet, geojson, wfs

My problem is two-fold. I am trying to load a WFS as a geojson on my map. The WFS contains universities and their information. When the map loads, all universities should be displayed, and on selection through checkbox, the universities need to filter based on different properties.
So far, I have managed to display the layer:

```
var rootUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/HEC/wfs';

var defaultParameters = {
    service: 'WFS',
    version: '1.0.0',
    request: 'GetFeature',
    typeName: 'HEC:Universities',
    maxFeatures: 200,
    outputFormat: 'application/json',
};

var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
var URL = rootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters);
    
var universities = L.geoJSON([],{
                        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                            return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
                        },
}).addTo(map);

$.ajax({
        url : URL,
        dataType : 'json',
        data: {},
        jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
        success: function (data){ 
            universities.addData(data);
    }
});
```

The problem is to remove the layer. If I remove the layer on the checkbox and add it again the filter does not apply:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function(){
    if(map.hasLayer(universities)){
        map.removeLayer(universities);
    }
    if((this).checked){
        if (this.id == "public"){
            
        }
        else if (this.id == "private"){ 
            
            $.ajax({
                    url : URL,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data: {
                        CQL_FILTER:"Sector='Private'"
                    },
                    jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
                    success: function (data){
                        universities.addData(data);
                        universities.addTo(map);
                }
            });
            
        }
        else{
            console.log("ERROR!")
        }
    }
    else{
        $.ajax({
                url : URL,
                dataType : 'json',
                data: {},
                jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
                success: function (data){
                    map.removeLayer(universities);
                    universities.addTo(map);
                }
        });
    
    }
});
```

Then I tried creating a new empty geojson and displaying the filtered data through it and removing the original layer. This didn't seem efficient but did what was needed. However, I am clueless on how to apply the style to it.

```
var x = new L.geoJSON();
```

Then filter becomes something like this:

```
else if (this.id == "private"){ 
            
            $.ajax({
                    url : URL,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data: {
                        CQL_FILTER:"Sector='Private'"
                    },
                    jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
                    success: function (data){
                        x.addData(data);
                        x.addTo(map);
                }
            });
            
        }
```

My questions are:

Is there a better way I can do this? I'd prefer to use only one geojson and not multiple.  If not, how do I style the new geojson?